# Postgres group by trimed mean

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am a newbie to SQL and am currently working with a dataset with the following structure:-

```
col1  col2  val id
 A     B     10  1
 B     C     20  1 
 A     B     30  2
 B     D      5  2
```

I want to get the trimmed mean(5%) of val for each group of (col1, col2), as well as total case count for each group where **val is greater than trimmed mean for that group**. The trimmed mean is supposed to match the value returned by `scipy.stats.trim_mean()` function

I am calculating the lower and upper limit for each group using the following piece of code

```
with bounds as (
select 
    avg(extract(epoch from val)) - 2 * stddev(extract(epoch from val)) as lower_bound,
    avg(extract(epoch from val)) + 2 * stddev(extract(epoch from val)) as upper_bound
from {table})
select * from bounds
```

but I am unsure about how I can use this piece of code along with `group by` on `col1` and `col2`.

any ideas on how I can get all the aggregated values in postgres?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the trimmed mean(5%) of val for each group of (col1, col2), as well as the number of values in each group where the val is greater than trimmed mean.

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions to calculate the average and standard deviation for the groups.  I also assume that the trimming is really "outside of two standard deviations".  If you really wanted to exclude 5% (or 2.5% of the highest and lowest values, then I would suggest you ask a new question -- and be sure to explain what to do when there are ties.

Then aggregate:

```
select col1, col2,
       avg(val) filter (where val between avg_val - 2 * stddev_val and avg_val + 2 * stddev_val) as trimmed_mean,
       count(*) filter (where val not between avg_val - 2 * stddev_val and avg_val + 2 * stddev_val) as extemes
from (select t.*,
             avg(val) over (partition by col1, col2) as avg_val,
             stddev(val) over (partition by col1, col2) as stddev_val
      from t
     ) t
group by col1, col2;
```

Note:  I have not used the `extract()` because the sample data looks like a number.  If it is really date/time data, you can add that into the query.

Comment: I've used `extract` since the val column is of type interval. I was running into issues while using stddev on column type interval. Using extract solved my problem.
Thanks for your help though! I'll try running this and see if it works out for me. :+1

Comment: On the top level query, we should do count(*) filter(where val  > trimmed_mean), but making this change breaks my query. Any ideas on how to change the query so that I can define extremes in this way?

Comment: @WitchKingofAngmar . . . This answers the question that was asked.  If you have a different question, ask a *new* question.